# Google maps isn`t showing properly

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to run this code in a browser, the google maps window appear, but the satelite or map image doesn`t show properly. I can hardly see the map or satelite image.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="no">
    <head>
    <title>Kontakt</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet type=text/css" href="stylesheetfgross.css">
    </head>

    <body>

     <header>
     <h1>Kontakt</h1>
     </header>

     <div id="map" style="width:400px;height:400px">



       <script>
      function myMap() {
          var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.234389, 11.137546),
              zoom: 10,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
          }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
      }
      </script>



    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>


    </body>
```

Comment: I don't see an [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) in your code

Comment: Working fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvXPGK | Maybe the issue is in your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted `function myMap()` from your code and google script looks like that right now: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>`, just deleted callback from url and it works now. Check [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ludaxord/j2dnL8o0/)

Comment: When you remove the callback you remove all the initialization settings / preferences as well.

Comment: Are you sure? I update my jsFiddle and everything works there.

Answer (score 0):

I used this, and it worked for me.

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" 
  src="key" allowfullscreen="">
</iframe>
```

Comment: I'd remove that key if I were you.